# Storing SeriesCollection Values in dynamical array

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic-arrays

I have the following issue: I create a chart from values that a user will insert in specific cells of a spreadsheet and the chart displays what I expect (The series are collected in the right way). The Series are created consecutively with 2 data points only.  I want to store the Xvalues (And YValues) of the series in dynamic arrays for performing calculations later (outside the series collection loop). I tried the following but the arrays only store the last values of the Series (despite using redim preserve everywhere).

Is it because the array is not redimensioned correctly?

Thanks for your help!

```
i = 1
SeriesAddedA = 1
RangeOccupiedA = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
RangeOccupiedB = Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row
MaxRangeOccupied = WorksheetFunction.Max(RangeOccupiedA, RangeOccupiedB)
Dim XValuesA()
Dim YValuesA()
ReDim XValues(RangeOccupiedA + 2)
ReDim YValues(RangeOccupiedA + 2)


Do While i < MaxRangeOccupied
    FilledCompA = NextFilled(Cells(i, 1))
    PrevCell = PrevFilled(Cells(i + 1, 1))
    rowdiff = FilledCompA - PrevCell
    
    If rowdiff < 2 And PrevCell <> 0 And FilledCompA <> 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve XValuesA(1 To RangeOccupiedA + 2)
        chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        chart.FullSeriesCollection(SeriesAddedA).Name = "Reaction Step A " & SeriesAddedA - 1
        chart.FullSeriesCollection(SeriesAddedA).XValues = "=" & "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'" & "!$E$" & FilledCompA - 1 & ":$E$" & FilledCompA
        chart.FullSeriesCollection(SeriesAddedA).Values = "=" & "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'" & "!$M$" & FilledCompA - 1 & ":$M$" & FilledCompA
        XValuesA() = chart.SeriesCollection(SeriesAddedA).XValues
        SeriesAddedA = chart.SeriesCollection.Count + 1
    ElseIf PrevCell <> 0 And rowdiff > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve XValuesA(1 To RangeOccupiedA + 2)
        chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        chart.FullSeriesCollection(SeriesAddedA).Name = "Reaction Step prev A " & SeriesAddedA - 1
        chart.FullSeriesCollection(SeriesAddedA).XValues = "=" & "(" & "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'" & "!$E$" & FilledCompA - rowdiff & "," & "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'" & "!$E$" & FilledCompA & ")"
        chart.FullSeriesCollection(SeriesAddedA).Values = "=" & "(" & "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'" & "!$M$" & FilledCompA - rowdiff & "," & "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'" & "!$M$" & FilledCompA & ")"
        XValuesA() = chart.SeriesCollection(SeriesAddedA).XValues
        SeriesAddedA = chart.SeriesCollection.Count + 1
    End If
loop

'the debug print says: 
XvaluesA(1) 310.52 
XvaluesA(2) 408.58
```

Comment: Fair. I'll try to better describe.

Comment: You `ReDim Preserve XValuesA(1 To RangeOccupiedA + 2)` in the loop but `RangeOccupiedA` does not change in the loop. So you can save you time and `ReDim` outside the loop right after `RangeOccupiedA = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row`. • Also your `ReDim XValues(RangeOccupiedA + 2)` in the very beginning does not make sense because at this time `RangeOccupiedA` is `0` because you didn't set the value yet.

Comment: Indeed, I tried but unfortunately, it does not seems to store the values as I want. Sorry I missed copied pasted. This should be correct now. That is not the entirety of the code I copied paste what was the most relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `XValuesA() = chart.SeriesCollection(SeriesAddedA).XValues` you overwrite the data in `XValuesA` everytime you call it in your loop. That is why it only contains the last values.

Use `XValuesA(i) = chart.SeriesCollection(SeriesAddedA).XValues` instead and then

```
Debug.Print XvaluesA(1)(1)
Debug.Print XvaluesA(1)(2)
```

gives the first values and

```
Debug.Print XvaluesA(2)(1)
Debug.Print XvaluesA(2)(2)
```

the second …

Comment: Oh my....this was actually working from the beginning (I tried your solution) but I just did not know how to debug.print the array correctly.